# How can I draw a circle sector with the ellipse class?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, canvas, ellipse, sector

I would like to make a sector of a circle on WP7. I tried to do this with the ellipse class and I found a lot of solution, which make a gauge or pie chart or something, but I need just the essence.
Could anyone help?

the aim is to show just one part of a circle (or ellipse). Like the yellow area in the picture:

[image]

Thanks, 
Laci

Comment: please provide more information, your question is not clear.

Comment: I'd like to show just one part of a circle (or ellipse). Like the yellow area in the [picture](http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWJgfC4v6tzKRjZBnARgoDiBl0yYhjPuA51ipzz4lWmZOM08dAWA).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple solution to the problem, though it does not use an `Ellipse` and it requires a little trigonometry:

```
<Path Fill="Black"
      Data="M0,0 L0,-100 A100,100 0 0 1 70.7,-70.7 z" />
```

The `Data` property uses [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx).

- The "M" at the beginning tells the pen to **M**ove to the location 0,0.
- The "L" tells the pen to draw a **L**ine from the current location (0, 0) to 0,-100.
- The "A" tells the pen to draw an elliptical **A**rc from the current location to 70.7,-70.7 (the "100,100" portion determines the horizontal and vertical radius of the ellipse and the "0 0 1" portion is for `RotationAngle`, `IsLargeArc`, and `SweepDirection` (1 for clockwise, 0 for counter-clockwise)).
- The "z" tells the pen to close or complete the shape (which will cause a line to be drawn from 70.7,-70.7 back to 0,0).

Where did the 70.7 come from? Well, this particular arc sweeps out an angle of 45 degrees from a circle with radius 100, so the coordinates 70.7,-70.7 are determined by `100 * sin(45)` and `100 * cos(45)`.

Comment: Cool answer but technically you are using 100 * sin(45 * (Pi/180)) and 100 * cos(45 * (Pi/180)) as you are using radians to get the x and y coordinate, not the degree.

Comment: Also, y coordinate should be multiplied by `-1`, since y-axis reversed, so:    `x = 100 * sin(45 * (Pi / 180))` and `y = -100 * cos(45 * (Pi / 180))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

- define a canvas wrapper for ellipse
- define the visible part of the canvas (clip). For this part you need to use [PathGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.aspx) as the Clip to define the slice of the circle you want to be visible. (see link)

  ```
  <Canvas>
      <Canvas.Clip>
          <PathGeometry>
                  // define your path here (see link above)
          </PathGeometry> 

          <Ellipse Background="Yellow" Width="200" Height="200" />
      </Canvas.Clip>
  </Canvas>
  ```

Alternatively you can use [CombinedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.aspx) to combine a `PathGeometry` and `EllipseGeometry` to form the slice. (the link provides a good example of `CombinedGeometry`)