# Writing a "Progress Pie" style for WPF ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to write a WPF style for ProgressBar that turns the standard bar in a "Progress pie".

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Style x:Key="ProgressPie" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Ellipse x:Name="PART_Track"
                                 Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                        <ed:Arc x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                                ArcThickness="1"
                                ArcThicknessUnit="Percent"
                                Fill="{StaticResource SomeStaticBrush}"
                                ToolTip="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                                EndAngle="{TemplateBinding Value}"/>

                        <ed:Arc x:Name="OuterPieBorder"
                                ArcThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel"
                                Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                StartAngle="0"
                                EndAngle="360"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Margin="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Unfortunately I have at least a couple problems:

- It seems that the width of `PART_Indicator` is bound to the `Value` of the template. How come? I haven't written anything to do so.
- I can't find a simple way to position `PART_Indicator` so that the center of the pie coincides with the center of `PART_Track`; any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that the width of PART_Indicator is bound to the Value of the template. How come? I haven't written anything to do so.

That is how templates works :) [see this for more explanations.](http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/2009/02/08/the-use-of-part_-in-control-templates/)

Regarding your second question I dont see any "magic answer" (I guess there isnt), but [this answer might help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667072/wpf-how-to-draw-arc-with-radius-and-start-and-stop-angle)

If you can read french, or you trust google translate, [there is this one as well](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/wpf-dessiner-un-arc-a-partir-d-un-centre-et-d-un-angle-98105) which does what you want, and seems pretty complete.

Comment: Thanks, while waiting for an answer I also found that out. To sum up:

 * The width of `PART_Indicator` is set to `Value * PART_Track` by the template and apparently there's nothing to do about it.

 * `Arc` doesn't allow to specify natively the position of the center point, to achieve that a custom shape is necessary.

Comment: You got it... But I dont see why this is an issue... you're not obliged to declare PART_Indicator, are you ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've tried to rename it and the application would still compile; however, I got a crash when trying to display the progress bar.

Comment: Ok, I never tried :) Just put a fake border with Visility="Collapsed" & x:Name="PART_Indicator", then !

Comment: I guess that would work, but the other issue would still remain. I'll have to think of something else.