# Java drawArc() method on Windows phone

Tags: c#, graphics, windows-phone

I would like to know if there is a simple way to draw an arc like in JAVA the [`drawArc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#drawArc%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method on Windows Phone.

I would like to be able to do something like in this thread : [How can I draw a circle sector with the ellipse class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744350/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-sector-with-the-ellipse-class) , but in a programmatic way.
I try to use `Path`, `PathGeometry` or `Ellipse` classes but I guess there must be something more simple.

Thank you

EDIT : I did this but I don't understand why my arc is not filled up correctly, if someone have a clue don't hesitate to share.

```
  public void fillArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)
    {

        try
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                lock (this.UIElements)
                {
                    Arc currentArc = new Arc();
                    currentArc.Height = (double)height;
                    currentArc.Width = (double)width;
                    currentArc.StartAngle = startAngle;
                    currentArc.EndAngle = arcAngle;
                    //Here I fill the Arc
                    currentArc.ArcThickness = 999;
                    currentArc.Fill = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
                    //                     
                    Canvas.SetLeft(currentArc, x);
                    Canvas.SetTop(currentArc, y);
                    Debug.WriteLine("fillArc hit ! Start Angle : " + startAngle + " End angle : " + arcAngle );
                    this.UIElements.Add(currentArc);
                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**: Code updated --> working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Microsof.Expression.Drawing` assembly to your project, and you will have the [`Arc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.shapes.arc%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) class available in your project.

To add the assembly to the project: *Right click on References -> Add reference -> Extensions -> Select Microsoft.Expression.Drawing -> OK*

`Arc` class resides in `Microsoft.Expression.Shapes` namespace.

Comment: I updated my Question, I used `Arc` as you suggested but I'm still facing some problem.

Comment: I think you need to set `currentArc.ArcThickness` property