# How can I draw a circle sector by a given percentage in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to draw a circle by given percentage. For example if the value 50 is given I would draw a half circle. I tried it with the first solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744350/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-sector-with-the-ellipse-class).

```
<Path Fill="Yellow"
            Data="M0,0 L0,-100 A100,100 0 0 1 70.7,-70.7 z" />
```

This didn't work for me and displayed this in the designer:

[image]

How could I modify the first solution or are there any better solutions to draw a sector of a circle for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, but you'll have to calculate the `70.7` values, and pass them to your XAML with a binding.

To convert an angle to x and y coordinates you need the `Math.Sin` and `Math.Cos` functions, which take an angle in radians. You can convert a percentage to an angle in radians by multiplying by `2*PI` and dividing by 100%, which can be combined like this:

```
var x = Math.Cos(myAngle * Math.Pi / 50)
var y = Math.Sin(myAngle * Math.Pi / 50)
```

Comment: If i understand it correct the positive 70.7 is x and the negative 70.7 is y?

Comment: Why is the sector displayed out of the Designer (image inside question) and how can I fix this?

Comment: In a `Path` M indicates the Startpoint, so move the Startpoint towards the Center (eg. `M200,200`)

Comment: 'L0, -100' is an instruction to draw a line 0 pixels horizonally and -100 pixels down (i.e. 100 pixels upwards from the top of the window). Co-ordinates start from the top left corner, so negative y values are above the top of the window (or above the start point, for relative values)